# IEEE Floating Point Numbers: Are they not "precise"? (read: well-defined)

Tags: sql-server, floating-point

For a long time I thought floating point arithmetic is well-defined and different platforms making the same calculation should get the same results. (Given the same rounding modes.)

Yet [Microsoft's SQL Server deems any calculation performed with floating point to have an "imprecise" result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns), meaning you can't have an index on it. This suggests to me that the guys at Microsoft thought there's a relevant catch regarding floating point.

So what is the catch?

EDIT: You can have indexes on floats in general, just not on computed columns. Also, geodata uses floating point types for the coordinates and those are obviously indexed, too. So it's not a problem of reliable comparison in general.

Comment: Floating point math is inherently imprecise in computers. There's tons of info about why, the common symptoms, and strategies for handling them out there.

Comment: @Will I don't think you understood me. This isn't about results needing to be rounded.

Comment: No, it's about being unable to precisely determine if two floating point numbers are equivalent. What use is an index if you cannot determine if the index value equals a given query value?

Comment: If you have an example, please give one. Right now I can only think of one. The only problem I see is x != x for NaN, but SQL Server could just define that differently for the index case. Is there anything else?

Comment: @Will: Testing for equality is not the issue. Floating-point numbers are easily tested for equality.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The docs disagree https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912.aspx "The float and real data types are known as approximate data types. The behavior of float and real follows the IEEE 754 specification on approximate numeric data types.
Approximate numeric data types do not store the exact values specified for many numbers; they store an extremely close approximation of the value." and "Avoid using float or real columns in WHERE clause search conditions, especially the = and <> operators. It is best to limit float and real columns to > or < comparisons."

Comment: @Will As I said before, this isn't about the necessity of rounding. You should avoid = in where-clauses not because it's not well-defined - it is - but because you may miss a number that is off by only a tiny amount (due to rounding). None of this has anything to do with the question.

Comment: Except for the catch that indexes over imprecise numbers are pointless because of the same exact reason. And if you still don't understand that, I'm at a loss. Good day to you, sir.

Comment: @Will: It is not possible to “follow the IEEE 754 specification on approximate numeric data types.” IEEE 754 defines only exact numeric data types. Clause 3.3 of IEEE 754 2008 specifies **exactly** the value represented by a finite floating-point datum. Microsoft’s documentation is low quality, and it is simply wrong to say that a floating-point datum stores ”an extremely close approximation.” IEEE 754 is clear: It is the **arithmetic** that is approximated, not the **numbers**. Each floating-point number is exactly one number, and it is either equal or not equal to another number.

Comment: @Will If they're pointless, then why are they what's been used for the components of geolocations, which can be indexed? You're talking nonsense and you're rude - not a good combination.

Comment: @Will: Also, the notion that floating-point numbers are “imprecise” while integers are not is easily demolished by the fact that `2/3` in integer arithmetic has a huge error. The mathematical error in the result is 100%. Yet nobody says integers are imprecise or that you cannot compare them. These myths about floating-point are due human misunderstanding, not mathematical properties or lack of specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating-point arithmetic is well defined by the IEEE 754 standard. In the documentation you point out, Microsoft has apparently not chosen to adhere to the standard.

There are a variety of issues that makes floating-point reproducibility difficult, and you can find Stack Overflow discussions about them by searching for [“[floating-point] reproducibility”](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfloating-point%5D+reproducibility). However, most of these issues are about lack of control in high-level languages (the individual floating-point operations are completely reproducible and specified by IEEE 754, and the hardware provides sufficient IEEE 754 conformance, but the high-level language specification does not adequately map language constructs to specific floating-point operations), differences in math library routines (functions such as `sin` and `log` are “hard” to compute in some sense, and vendors implement them without what is called *correct rounding*, so each vendor’s routines have slightly different error characteristics than others), multithreading and other issues allow operations to be performed in different orders, thus yielding different results, and so on.

In a single system such as Microsoft’s SQL Server, Microsoft presumably could have controlled these issues if they wanted to. Still, there are issues to consider. For example, a database system may have a `sum` function that computes the sum of many things. For speed, you may wish the `sum` implementation to have the flexibility to add the elements in any order, so that it can take advantage of multiprocessing or of adding the elements in whatever order they happen to be stored in. But adding floating-point data using elementary add operations of the same floating-point format has different results depending on the order of the elements. To make the sum reproducible, you have to specify the order of operation or use extra precision or other techniques, and then performance suffers.

So, not making floating-point arithmetic is a **choice** that is made, not a consequence of any lack of specification for floating-point arithmetic.

Another problem for database purposes is that even well defined and completely specified floating-point arithmetic has NaN values. (NaN, an abbreviation for Not a Number, represents a floating-point datum that is not a number. A NaN is produced as the result of an operation that has no mathematical result (such as the real square root of a negative number). NaNs act as placeholders so that floating-point operations can continue without interruption, and an application can complete a set of floating-point operations and then take action to replace or otherwise deal with any NaNs that arose.) Because a NaN does not represent a number, it is not equal to anything, not even itself. Comparing two NaNs for equality produces false, even if the NaNs are represented with exactly the same bits. This is a problem for databases, because NaNs cannot be used as a key for looking up records because a NaN search key will never equal a NaN in the key field of a record. Sometimes this is deal with by defining two different ordering relations—one is the usual mathematical comparison, which defines less than, equal to, and greater than for numbers (and for which all three are false for NaNs), and a second which defines a sort order and which is defined for all data, including NaNs.

It should be noted that each floating-point datum that is not a NaN represents a certain number **exactly**. There is no imprecision in a floating-point number. A floating-point number does not represent an interval. Floating-point **operations** approximate real arithmetic in that they return values approximately equal to the exact mathematical results, while floating-point numbers are **exact**. Elementary floating-point operations are exactly specified by IEEE 754. Lack of reproducibility arises in using different operations (including the same operations with different precisions), in using operations in different orders, or in using operations that do not conform to the IEEE 754 standard.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much. Very enlightening.